# Request.Body ReadCloser : does it need to be closed by the caller

Tags: go

os.File is a ReadCloser, and the defer fd.Close() return a error: file is already closed. My question is that will Request.Body be closed no matter when request finished?
If I Assign a ReadCloser to http.Request.Body, do I need to close the ReadCloser myself?

```golang
package main
import (

"log"

"net/http"

"os"

)


func main() {

fd, err := os.Open("test")

if err != nil {

log.Fatal(err)

}

// return err: file is already closed

defer fd.Close()

//req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", "http://localhost:8080/test.txt", fd)

if err != nil {

log.Fatal(err)

}


client := &http.Client{}
res, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer res.Body.Close()

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from [`Client.Do()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Do):

> The request Body, if non-nil, will be closed by the underlying Transport, even on errors.

So yes, do you not need to close it. Some `ReadCloser` has an idempotent `Close()` method which means closing it multiple times does no harm, but as you experienced, there are cases when calling `Close()` multiple times results in an error. So when using it for the request body, do not close it.

Comment: @agin719 please accept the answer if it helped, to close this question out.